# check if the device supports 4K

Tags: android

I have a task to check if the android device supports 4K or not before playing a specific video.
I’ve tried to check some options but could’t find a neat solution for this task.
One of them is to use MediaCodec for getting videoCapabilities but It doesn’t give me what i'm looking for.
I also tried a solution that i saw:
[Detecting 4K UHD screens on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557228/detecting-4k-uhd-screens-on-android)
Is there a way to detect if a device is capable of outputting at 4K UHD in advance ?

Comment: check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844734/check-if-android-device-support-4k-video

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the pixels on the screen and do the action accordingly. We know that 4K UHD screen has 3840 x 2160 pixels. So in your code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

if(width >= 2160 && height >= 3840)
   //means support UHD. do the job.
```

Comment: You forgot to mention you took your answer from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to stackoverflow so, next time I'll make sure to refer to the topic. :)